# Syntax Error: Binary Integer Class Problem in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax-error

Having some issues with the for loop in my binaryNumber project. Does anyone know what the issue is with this section of the code? The error eclipse is giving me says: Syntax error on token "<", Expression expected after this token.

My code is have so far is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

//Binary Class defined
public class BinaryNumber {
    private int digits[];
    private boolean overFlow= false;
    
    //constructor for binary number strings
    public BinaryNumber(String str) {
        digits= new int[str.length()];
        
        //for loop to iterate through the strings

        for(i=0; i<[str.length()];i++){
            
        digits[i]= str.charAt(i)-'0';
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //binary constructor for binary numbers
    public BinaryNumber(int length) {
        digits= new int[length];
    
    }
```

Appreciate any help, not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You don't need square brackets around the conditional string length in the for statement (and you can't have them; it's invalid syntax and non-sensical).

Comment: `[str.length()]` - why does this mean?

Comment: @DaveNewton I got it working thank you!!